# Making appointments in Calcurse without using interactive CLI interface

Tags: bash, cron

I'd like to make a automated script so I could enter some repeating events in Calcurse.

Is there a way to do this without using the interactive interface?

Comment: https://calcurse.org/files/manual.html

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question. Is there a command I could execute in a automated script? Thanks!

Comment: If it's not in their manual I would assume no.  I don't feel like reading their manual though because I will likely never use the program.